# Javascript to update List field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, splistitem

I have created a script to pull data from a URL. I have managed to store the data to a variable but am a little stuck on how to set it to a list form field.

This is an example of the snippet I was using to do it.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-    3.1.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getQuery(){
     var query_string = {};
     var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
     var link= query.split("&");

     for(var i=0; i<link .length;i++) {
        var pair = link[i].split("=");
        var pair2 = pair[1].split("%3D")

        if(pair2[0] === "%3Fduns") {
          //$("input[title='name']").val(pair2[0]);  
          //setFieldValue('name',pair2[0]);
        }
      }
     return param;
   }

</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update the SharePoint ListItem with value from URL using Javascript:

```
var parVal;
function getQuery(){
     var query_string = {};
     var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
     var link= query.split("&");

     for(var i=0; i<link .length;i++) {
        var pair = link[i].split("=");
        var pair2 = pair[1].split("%3D")

        if(pair2[0] === "%3Fduns") {
          //$("input[title='name']").val(pair2[0]);  
          //setFieldValue('name',pair2[0]);
        }
      }
     parVal = param; // store param to parVal variable
     updateListItem(); // Call update function
   }

    function updateListItem() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List1'); // Get List

        this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(3); // 3=ID which item you want to update
        oListItem.set_item('name', parVal); // set value 'parVal' from query to field
        oListItem.update();

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert('Item updated!');
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Here, assuming that `param` is the value you have to set to `name` field.

Comment: Thanks for that, however in updateList Item() the code never runs past

Comment: var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); - Do you know why?

Comment: Unable to get property 'get_current' of undefined or null reference

Comment: try to call updateListItem() function like:   SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', updateListItem);